# How to escape special characters (other than <>&'") in golang templates?

Tags: go, character-encoding, go-templates

Go templates auto-escape but only the five characters <>&' and " (see [html.EscapeString](https://golang.org/pkg/html/#EscapeString))

so this code like

```
check := func(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
t, err := template.New("foo").Parse(`{{define "T"}}special chars: {{.}}{{end}}`)
check(err)
err = t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "T", "<>&' äåüöß")
check(err)
```

returns (as you can check here: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/q8B-8kM_GL))

```
special chars: &lt;&gt;&amp;&#39; äåüöß
```

So how do i use golang templates to render text that may contain characters like äåüöß?

It's not like i could escape these myself, because e.g. "ä" escapes to "&auml;" which means that efter i escape manually, golang just escapes the "&" character part of that a second time and i get "&amp;auml;" (but the html-file should contain a single escaped "&auml;" so that the browser displays an "ä").

Comment: Why do you need to escape / use entities for those characters?  They're fine in both utf-8 and iso-8859-1 encodings, I believe...

Comment: because i'm a german guy living in Sweden, so data (e.g. last names) may contain these characters and currently an "ö" looks like "Ã¶".

Comment: What character encoding is your HTML document specifying?  (ideally, can you link us to the page you are viewing?   server can override document setting...)

Comment: none :D which should i use? (yes, the answer may be so simple) <!DOCTYPE html>
<html> ...

Comment: Try adding `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` in the `<head/>`...

Comment: yes, that fixed it! Do you want to write an Answer so i can click on "answered" and you get some points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These characters are fine as-is in modern browsers, but you'll need to specify a character encoding in your webpage.

Add the line

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

in your document's head.

For more on character encodings in HTML, see the [W3C documentation](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations.en).